# Why does Python disables MSCRT assertions when built with debug mode?

Tags: python, crt, assertion

Python disables MSCRT assertions for debug mode during the initialization of exceptions module when it is built in debug mode. At least from the source code, I can see Python 2.6.5 doing this for _MSC_VER >= 1400 i.e. Visual C++ 2005. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this thread](http://bugs.python.org/issue4804) on the bug tracker.

Comment: These comments seem to be explaining why various complex verifications are performed, not why assertions are disabled.  Disabling assertions when building Python wouldn't disable these, anyway: the above are assertions in the C runtime itself, not in code being built for Python.

Comment: That makes sense, searching around the bug tracker turns up a thread explaining this issue.